# What is the Center of a Rectangle2D?

Tags: java, awt, rectangles

If I have a rectangle with a width of 4 pixels shouldn't its center be at pixel 1.5?
[image]

Rectangle2D.Float.getCenterX() returns 2, leaving two pixels to the left of center and one pixel to the right. For the record:

```
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class CenterXcoDemo2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Rectangle2D rect    = new Rectangle2D.Float( 0, 0, 4, 4 );
        System.out.println( rect.getCenterX() );
    }
}
```

Comment: I think for the Rectangle class the width should be thought of as a width, and not as a pixel index.  So `(0,0,4,4)` means a *width* of four pixels, and not pixels 0..4, like 0, 1, 2, 3.  A width of 2 means pixels 0 and 1.

Comment: @markspace Good point. But the documentation says "Returns the X coordinate...," and an x-coordinate of 2 pushes all my calculations to the right of center.

Comment: *one pixel to the right.* - not sure how you get one to the right. In your example you get 0, 1 pixels to the left and 2, 3 pixels to the right. That is, if you want to paint over half the rectangle you would start at pixel 2. I would be more concerned with a rectangle of width 5 that returns a center point of 2.5. I don't know how you draw a pixel starting at 2.5. I think you need to clarify the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @camickr You might not be able to find a *physical* pixel located at x=1.5, but given that Rectangle2D.Float allows you to set the x-coordinate and width of a rectangle to fractional values you should be able to at least imagine a *virtual* location at x=1.5. Perhaps the clarification you need is that the picture I drew locates the center of the rectangle where *I* think it belongs. If drew the center where *Rectangle2D* thinks it belongs it would be pointing to pixel 2, leaving pixel 0 and 1 to the left and 3 to the right.

Comment: See also [`java.awt.Graphics2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics2D.html), which elaborates on the distinction between coordinates and pixels.